# htaccess too many redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a wordpress website. Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule "abc/"    "new-url-abc/" [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

So, using as input url **https://foo.bar/abc/** the output url is **https://foo.bar/new-url-abc/**

This rule is correctly applied but can't reach output url. I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I have to comment this rewrite url otherwise I can't even reach **https://foo.bar/new-url-abc/** directly.

Comment: `new-url-abc/` still matches the pattern `abc/`, so this gets redirected again … and again. Anchor your pattern to the start: `^abc/`

Comment: for some url i resolved using /abc/ /new-url/abc/, but for some urls doesn't work. At  the end I renamed pages and avoid redirects.